# Array of Functions in Javascript That Calls a Function From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So I want to create a `function`:

1. That takes in an array of strings
2. Converts those strings into functions
3. Then is able to return that function when called from the array

So far my code looks like this:

```
function funcArrays(stringArray){
      var funcArray = [];
      for(var i in stringArray){
         var name = stringArray[i];
         var func = new Function(
             "return function(num){ return"+" "+name+"; };"
           )();
         funcArray.push(func());

      }
       return funcArray;
 }
```

When I pass this `function` an array of strings

`var strings = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']`

However, when I try to pass this array to my function like this:

`var functionalArrayPositionOne = funcArrays(strings)`

I get this:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: One is not defined
    at eval (eval at funcArrays (:5:14), <anonymous>:2:30)
    at guestListFns (<anonymous>:8:18)
    at <anonymous>:1:9`

And what I would want to be able to do is this:

`var functionalArrayPositionOne = funcArrays(strings)`

Then do this:
`functionalArrayPositionOne[0]()`

And have this return the `function's` output

Comment: Sorry if I missed it but where is the `guestListFns(strings)`?

Comment: Also, in this line `new Function(
             "return function(num){ return"+" "+name+"; };"
           )()` you are calling the function you created, so you dont have a function

Comment: Good catch I changed all the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error arises because:

```
function funcArrays(stringArray){
  var funcArray = [];
  for(var i in stringArray){
     var name = stringArray[i];
     var func = new Function(
         "return function(num){ return"+" "+name+"; };"
       )(); // this call
     funcArray.push(func());
     // here you end up calling 'One'  which is not a function

  }
   return funcArray;
}
```

1. You are calling the function you just created, therefore you have the returned value instead of the function which seems to be your requirement.
2. If you use the function constructor you won't have access to the variable created in the scope. So you get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: One is not defined`.

---

```
function funcArrays(stringArray){
  var funcArray = [];
  for(var i in stringArray){
     var func = function() {
       var name = stringArray[i];
       return function () { //[1] 
         return (function () { //[2]
           return name //[3]
         })()
       }
     }
     funcArray.push(func());
  }
   return funcArray;
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
var functionalArrayPositionOne = funcArrays(['One', 'Two', 'Three'])[0]
functionalArrayPositionOne()
// prints 'One'
```

But why 3 functions?

If you see through this case:

```
var func = function () {
  return function () {
    return name
  }
}
```

The value in funcArray would be:

```
function () {
  return name
}
```

After the entire execution of your loop you will see the last value of `name`.

So to freeze the value of `name` I used an IIFE [2]

Comment: Why is it necessary to use the `Function` constructor at all?

Comment: It is not, I am just pointing out the reason why OP got that error. :) I personally dont like doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The function you end up executing is actually

```
function(num) { return One; }
```

and yes, `One` is indeed undefined, hence your error. If you wanted the function to return the **string** `'One'`, then you needed to write:

```
var func = new Function(
    "return function(num){ return '" + name + "'; };"
)();
```

Note the single quotation marks. This would generate a function like you want:

```
function(num) { return 'One'; }
```

By the way, in such cases it is often more readable to use template strings:

```
`return function(num) { return '${name}'; }`
```

But actually, you don't need to use the `Function` constructor to create functions at all; we already have the `function` keyword to do that. So instead of

```
var func = new Function(
    "return function(num){ return"+" "+name+"; };"
)();
```

Just write

```
var func = function() {
  return function(num) { return name; };
}();
```

However, if you think about it, you are defining a function which returns a function, then immediately executing that function, which is exactly the same as just specifying the function itself, so

```
var func = function(num) { return name; };
```

Since you are doing this in a loop across `strings`, it is a good application for `map`, allowing you to write your entire function as:

```
function funcArrays(stringArray){
  return stringArray.map(string => function(num) { return string; });
}
```

To take a more functional approach, it is often useful to write a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) which creates a function which always returns some particular value. Sometimes such a function is called `K`:

```
function K(v) { return function() { return v; }
```

or, if you prefer

```
const K = v => () => v;
```

Now you can write your `funcArrays` function simply as

```
function funcArrays(stringArray) { 
  return stringArray.map(K); 
}
```

In general, there are very few cases where you will need to use the `Function` constructor to create a function from a string. If you try to, you will often find yourself confused and in trouble. Using the `Function` constructor has most of the same problems as using `eval`, and is equally problematic. Among other problems, you will only be able to access global variables (or parameters) from the function so created.